# React Swiper breaks slideTo on loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, swiper.js

I'm using `Swiper React` in `Next.js` to make a carousel on my website, the thing is that carousel is controlled by external buttons using `slideTo` function, everything works correctly until it passes from slide 3 to 4 or -1 (there are 3 slides, so slide 4 is slide 1 and slide -1 is slide 3 but in loop); when this happens, `slideTo` will break and go to a completly different postion of the slider.

Exmaples:

From Slide 4 (1 in loop):

- to Slide 1 will go to Slide 2
- to Slide 2 will go to Slide 3
- to Slide 3 will stay in same position

And so it goes with Slide 5, 6, -1, -2 and others.

If last explanation is hard to understand, try to do a loop and use the buttons in this code:

`page.tsx`

```
'use client'

import React from 'react'
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide, useSwiper } from 'swiper/react'
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import 'swiper/css'
import Item from './Item';

function TestPage() 
{
    const dummyArray = [...Array(3).keys()];

    return (
        <div className='w-full h-[100dvh]'>
            <Swiper loop className='h-full'>

                {dummyArray.map((elem, index) =>

                 <SwiperSlide className='h-full' key={uuid()}> 
                    <Item dummyArray={dummyArray} slideIndex={index}/>
                 </SwiperSlide>
                 
                )}

            </Swiper>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TestPage
```

`Item.tsx`

```
'use client'

import React from 'react'
import { useSwiper } from 'swiper/react';

import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

interface ItemProps {
    dummyArray: number[],
    slideIndex: number,
}

function Item(props: ItemProps) {
    const { dummyArray, slideIndex } = props;

    const swiper = useSwiper();

    const handleClick = (index: number) => {
        swiper.slideTo(index)
    }

    return (
        <div className='h-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center'>
            Slide {slideIndex+1}

            <div className='flex gap-4'>

                {dummyArray.map((elem, index) => // This is actually another component but it is this way here due to simplicity
                    <button key={uuid()} onClick={() => handleClick(index)}>
                        Go to slide {index+1}
                    </button>
                )}

            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Item
```